# How to loop through image folder with paintings in Blazor server?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am using Blazor server. I have paintings in a wwwroot/paintings folder. The painting names are all in the format "XX by YY". I need to generate links to each painting using its name, so the link will also say "XX by YY." I can't know the names ahead of time.

How can I load the paintings into an array, or what is the best way to do this?

Comment: In Blazor Server you can simply read all files using Directory.GetFiles. You'll then need to parse the filename as you want by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"...\wwwroot\paintings\");
FileInfo[] files = d.GetFiles();

foreach (FileInfo filepath in files)
    Console.WriteLine(filepath.Name);
```

last two lines just to print the names of all files you find. If needed you can specify file format in `GetFiles()` by putting for example "*.jpg" parameter