# Display Images located in wwwroot folder with a foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, wwwroot

I need to display employee names and their corresponding image below on a blazor webpage, So far I have the names displayed fine but can only loop through one image due to not knowing how to loop through the wwwroot folder so each name has the same image.

```
<h1>Northwind Employees</h1>



@foreach (Employee employee in NorthWindEmployees)
{
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">
        @employee.FirstName @employee.LastName <br>
    </h3>
    <div width="100" height="100" style="vertical-align:middle; text-align:center">
        <img src="/images/EmpID1.jpg" /> //the reason for each name having the same image
    </div>
}


@code {
    public List<Employee> NorthWindEmployees;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Northwind db = new Northwind();
        NorthWindEmployees = db.Employees.ToList();
    }
}
```

How do I loop through the \wwwroot\images\ folder to display each employee image with their name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to loop through image folder with paintings in Blazor server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73454259/how-to-loop-through-image-folder-with-paintings-in-blazor-server)

Comment: @The2Step Yes, to an extent, thank you. I now need to figure out how to display each image in the loop, (I am new to HTML and C#) as it prints each image name to the console for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I loop through the \wwwroot\images\ folder to display each
> employee image with their name?

Let's say, you have Image folder within your wwwroot. In this scenario, you would need to access that image as following:

[image]

As you can see, I have ImageNameFolder inside wwwroot so you would access it as following:

```
 <img src="ImageFolder/ImageName"
                     class="rounded-square"
                     height="50" width="75"
                     style="border:1px"
                     accept="image/*" />
```

**When you would have List:**

Let's assume your NorthWindEmployees model looks as like below:

```
public class NorthWindEmployees 
    {
        

        public string? EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public string? ImageName { get; set; }
       
       
    }
```

Therefore, you would access it as following:

```
@foreach (Employee employee in NorthWindEmployees)
            {
            
             <h3 style="text-align: center;">
                    @employee.EmployeeName  <br>
            </h3>
           <div width="100" height="100" style="vertical-align:middle; text-align:center">
                  <img src="Image/@employee.ImageName"
                         class="rounded-square"
                         height="50" width="75"
                         style="border:1px"
                         accept="image/*" />
            </div>
                
            }
```

**Note:** You can use styte either in your src or in div as well.

**Complete Demo:**

[image]

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Employee Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Employee Picture
            </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var employees in NorWindsEmployeeList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @employees.EmployeeName
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="Image/@employees.ImageName"
                     class="rounded-square"
                     height="50" width="75"
                     style="border:1px"
                     accept="image/*" />
                </td>
               
             
            </tr>

        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@code {

    public class NorWindsEmployees
    {
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public string ImageName { get; set; }
    }

    List<NorWindsEmployees> NorWindsEmployeeList = new List<NorWindsEmployees>()
            {
                new NorWindsEmployees(){ EmployeeName ="A",ImageName = "China_Flag.jpg"},
                new NorWindsEmployees(){ EmployeeName ="B",ImageName = "du.png"},
                new NorWindsEmployees(){ EmployeeName ="C",ImageName = "Kiron.gif"},
            };
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on it [you could check our official document here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/images?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much! It works perfectly - an excellent and descriptive answer!

Comment: Thanks for your response. Glad to assist you on this.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a field called Image Location to your employee entity, then use that to locate the image.

```
<img src=@employee.ImageLocation />
```